# Silverlight Hyperlink button with image (hover effect on the image)

Tags: silverlight, image, hyperlink, hover

I am trying to create a hyperlink button with an image where image would have a hover effect (changed on MouseOver). I was able to create a hyperlink button with one image, but stuck on hover effect on the image. Please help!

Here is my User Control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="NavigationButton_Middle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                            To="White"
                                                            Duration="00:00:0.1">
                                            </ColorAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Edge" BorderBrush="#FFD9D9D9" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Height="32" Width="48">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4" />
                                </Border.Background>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="HomeButton" Style="{StaticResource NavigationButton_Middle}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Home" Visibility="Visible" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Image Source="home.png" Margin="13,5,13,5" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                </HyperlinkButton>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change the actual content of the button (which is unknown to the Style), it is hard to do without hurting the re-usability of the style. However, if you don't mind that, you can move the Image inside the Template, where the ContentPresenter is now.  Then you can modify it by name from your storyboard.